# List of densities for different android devices

Tags: android

Is there a list of density values for different android devices? I know how to check it programmatically but I this doesn't work if I don't have a specific device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, if you know the screen resolution of the device you can determine what density bucket it's going to fall into.  This is because density is a function of resolution and physical size, and manufacturers tend to pick a screen size that fits the display resolution.  As such, here is a list I use of all the common resolutions found on the market.

**LDPI:** QVGA (320x240), WQVGA (432x240)

**MDPI:** HVGA (480x320), WXGA (1280x800), SVGA (1024x600)

**HDPI:** WVGA (800x480), FWVGA (854x480)

The reason those two really high resolutions exist in MDPI is because they are only used on tablets, which have a larger screen size...so the dpi rating works out to still be in the midrange.

Also, you may find this information on [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) useful, from the Developer portal.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

use this code for it frnd: scale gives you density:

for low scale:0.75

for medium scale:1.0

for large scale:1.5

```
float scale; 
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();                             
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

scale =getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```